# Using 'onclick' in html for a javascript function only working once

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

Very briefly, I'm trying to create a way to slide out a `div` and make it visible by `clicking` a button on the `webpage`. I have the css and the layout looking correct and the `animation` runs once but then doesn't work again.

this is the full js file

```
var button1Toggle;
var button2Toggle;
var button3Toggle;

button1Toggle = false;

function slideOutFunc() {
    if (button1Toggle == false) {
        document.getElementById('fade-in1').style.left = '0';
        document.getElementById('fade-in1').style.opacity = '1';
        button1Toggle = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('fade-in1').style.left = '-33vw';
        document.getElementById('fade-in1').style.opacity = '0';
        button1Toggle = true;
    }
}
```

`<button id="clickApply" class="applyButton" onclick="slideOutFunc()"><a>Apply</a></button>`

this is the `html portion` that calls the function

Any help understanding why it only works once would be appreciated.

Comment: your `else` block should set `button1Toggle = false;`, right?

Comment: FYI: That code can be cleaned up a tons by toggling a class.

Answer (score 0):

Both conditions in `sildeOutFunc` set `buttonToggle` to `true`